# How can I insert a space between several clips in Premiere?

Tags: premiere

In Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015 I want to select 20 or more clips to drop on the timeline at once (in this case they are audio clips).  However I would like to have a configurable space or gap between each clip on the timeline (say a 5 second space between each clip) rather than having them be one right after the other.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The best way I've found is based off of "User" above but much simpler, no need to copy and paste:

1. Drag and drop all 20+ clips on to the timeline to add them.
2. Press 'a' and hold Shift, then click on the leftmost clip on the sequence to select all video clips to the right of the first clip on a single track.
3. Right click and choose Speed/Duration. Choose a setting like 95% (relatively small gap, enough to be able to set Default Transitions on multiple clips all at once using a single sequence) and check Ripple Edit, Shifting Trailing Clips. This is the important part.
4. Right click the selected clips again and choose Speed/Duration. Set the Speed back to 100% and uncheck Ripple Edit, Shifting Trailing Clips.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I figured out a workaround to do this (based on the idea of using the speed duration from [putting a gap between each clip](https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/3/906798))

1. Drag and drop all 20+ clips on to the timeline to add them.
2. Select on the clips and copy them onto a new audio track
3. Select all the new clips you just copied and right click and choose `Speed/Duration`.  Choose a setting like 50% and check `Ripple Edit, Shifting Trailing Clips`
4. Delete the clips on the new track you just copied and time stretched, leaving you with just the original clips.

The original clips should now be spaced out.  Obviously could be problematic if you have lots of other stuff on your timeline but you could lock those tracks.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate 5 seconds of silence and do an insert edit between each one. It's pretty easy with the keyboard shortcuts - in the timeline window <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> and so on

Comment: Sound promising can you flesh this out a little more? As it is now I don't know how to do it:  1. How to generate 5 seconds of silence? And how to insert edit? When I press the comma key nothing happens.  I'm on Windows if that makes any difference

Comment: You could generate 5 seconds of silence with Audition, if you have it. Make a new waveform file and go to edit>insert>silence and save the file out. Otherwise you could do the same with Audacity (free), or you could probably download silence from the internet (make sure you get silence that's licensed under a creative commons license though ;). As for the insert edits, comma is the default key for insert edit on Windows and Mac, at least on US English keyboards. Check your keyboard shortcuts ( Ctrl-Alt-K ).

Comment: My comma key is set for `Application->Clip->Insert`. When you press the comma key, how does premiere know what you want to insert?  I'm thinking there must be a step before this

Comment: oh, sorry, yes you need the clip in your source window. Without in and out points set it should insert the whole clip, otherwise in the source window hit `x` to select the whole clip.

Comment: Ok it still wasn't working but after some searching I found I needed to select a track for source patching (see https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1420758).  I had selected tracks in the "track target column" but not in the "source indicator column" (as described here: https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/source-patching-track-targetting.html)

Comment: Also it looks like the cleaner way to do this is to have the source patcher in the black/silent state by Alt clicking in the "source indicator column" in the track headers and then doing the insert edit as you suggested.  This way instead of having silent audio you actually have a true empty gap between the clips.

Answer (score 0):

I know the easiest way: first select all the clips you want to move to the right to create space, right click on them and tap 'group' now they are all considered as one clip. Now all you have to is drag it to the right and later if you want to select only one file just right click on the whole group and then press 'ungroup'. That's it, you're done.